# Do any of our scriptures mention benefits of having a girl child?

Tags: vedas, puranas, advaita, shaktism, smarta

In traditional or even modern-day India, I hear from my elders that the birth of a girl baby is not as welcoming as a boy baby.

I also heard from elders that during Punyavachanam a special portion/mantra/procedure is done for the child if it's a boy. This is not done/skipped if it's a girl child. I am not sure what this is. Please let me know if someone knows.

Can someone state a few good things about a female child being preferred over a male child according to Hindu shastras/traditions?

Comment: In śāstras, where does it state that the birth of daughter is in anyway lesser to that of a son? Or instead where does it say that the a son is superior to a daughter, the former being more worth investing? I guess you are confusing societal viewpoints with the scriptural viewpoints.

Comment: I heard that are some extra rituals that is done during Punyavachaham for a male child but not for a girl child? Is it true? Also, i just want to understand whether there is any bias between the genders in our shastras
 Also please mention of significance of girl child when it's better than a male child if there's something mentioned in Shashtras. @Bingming

Comment: I don't remember exactly but somewhere it was stated that a daughter embodies Lakshmi. And I don't know about punyahavachana but it is true that the birth of a girl child isn't considered to be welcoming on the same scale as that of a boy because while the birth of a boy is celebrated by hemasrāddha, the same isn't done in case of a girl.

Comment: Although birth of a boy is truly favoured in our texts but in no way does the same texts sanction the misogynistic barbaric practices of Jaths & Rajputs.

Comment: @AnubrataBit, thank you for your comment
 Could you please help me with the term hemasraddha? Also, can you share some references in our texts that favour the birth of a male child?

Comment: @Newbie  I don't know much about Punyavachaham, sorry about that.

Comment: @Bingming, thank you. Do you know any references from our texts that favour the birth of a male child ?

Comment: I will have to check, I don't know now. I am not sure if there is an explicit bias for a son over daughter in the scriptures.

Comment: As for the cultural practices, it varies from place to place. Where I am from, we usually value a daughter as much or even more than a son. Many people pray to have a girl child. So, if someone states that the whole of Hindu tradition favors son over daughter, that would be pretty wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Bingming. Would really appreciate if you would write up an answer if time permits with necessary references that help me understand the answer

Comment: “misogynistic barbaric practices of Jaths & Rajputs.” <—— It wouldn’t be accurate to paint a whole huge group of people as being one way. Rajput/Kshtriya girl vs boy birth practices & beliefs are not all “misogynistic barbaric” in general. What ? No. I’ve read many inaccurate things on here re Rajputs that are kinda ridiculous. It would be like me saying all Kashmir persons behave certain way, have certain beliefs & customs, or something like that. Inaccurate. Re Rajputs there isn’t gender parity, let’s not get carried away haha, no, of course. But it isn’t 100% the other extreme either.

Comment: Again, 'I heard from somewhere' is not a reference.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, yes, I understand. I am not able to find the exact reference. But I have only heard the sayings and practices by word of mouth. In that case, could you please let me know your thoughts on this topic?

Comment: @veganenvironmentalist Around the early 19th century, records emerged that Jaths & Rajputs indulged in a practice of female infanticide through methods like burying the infant girl underground immediately after birth & strangling the infant with her own umbilical cord in order ensure boys didn't had to face competition from their sisters for parental care & resources in future.The British government banned these practices through Act VIII of 1870 & the Arya Samaj vigorously campaigned against this monstrosity. By the term 'misogynistic barbaric practices', I referred to this practice.